# Expo: iOs build fails because of pod installation

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, cocoapods

I've built an expo app, which I would like to deploy. I am working on a Windows machine, and using eas to build the app. I've done that one time before a couple of days ago with no issues, but now it fails because of POD installation?
I don't have any background with iOs or developing natively for apple, so not sure what that means.
It says something about a timeout, and I have been experiencing some internet issues, but the build happens anyway on Expo's servers no? It can't happen on my machine as I have a Windows machine.

Don't want to keep trying and failing as I'll run out of my free tier.

What might be the issue here? This is the error log I'm getting

[image]